# Why do we say let x = soething as opposed to x = something?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In algebra word problems, we use `let x = some variable` as opposed to `x = some variable`. I've been told that we can't use just `x`, but I've never understood why.

Why is this?

Eg from my calc textbook: [image]

Comment: Because the second is not a sentence?

Comment: I think there were some situation where my teacher would tell us to write let x = when not even working on word problems.

Comment: I've been told ... but I've never understood why $\implies$ ask the person who told you that. Otherwise you're getting a poll of what internet people think of what your teacher thought when they said what you said they said.

Answer (score 4):

"*Let$\ldots$*" is a definition. The extract is stating that $V$ is the volume of the balloon but you wouldn't need to prove this because they've *let* it be true. There is no need to prove a statement that is given. However, when the extract says "$\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{9}{2}$", this is because it can be proved from what has been stated earlier.

In brief, the difference is that statements with "*let*" are definitions while statements without it may not be. You could say $V=\ldots$ without the "*let*" though including it shows that you're defining $V$ as such.

**Remark**: "*Let*" doesn't need to be included in all circumstances; though it's not the area you were asking about, you could define variables differently in many programming languages. E.g. $\mathrm{int}\,x$ or $\mathrm{float}\,x$.